# Signing a SimpleDB request

Tags: python, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to make an API call to Amazon's SimpleDB service with Python. As an example, I'm using the simplest request there is to make, `ListDomains`. No matter what I try, however, the response is always "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided."

This is the string I'm signing (as per [documentation here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?REST_RESTAuth.html)):

```
GET
https://sdb.amazonaws.com/
/
AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&Action=ListDomains&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2011-04-19T18%3A50%3A43&Version=2009-04-15
```

I'm signing it with the following code:

```
import base64,hashlib,hmac,time                                            
# Sign the request                                                                           
signature = hmac.new(                                                                        
    key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,                                                               
    msg=string_to_sign,                                                                      
    digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest()                                                         
# Base64 encode the signature                                                                
signature = base64.encodestring( signature )
```

I've tried it with both HmacSHA256 and HmacSHA1. Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are properly URL encoding all of your HTTP paramater values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key issue is that you have to properly URL encode all of the HTTP parameter values.

The following documentation has disappeared from the SimpleDB docs, but can be found in the SQS docs and is still very relevant to SimpleDB:

> Do not URL encode any of the
>   unreserved characters that RFC 3986
>   defines.
>
> These unreserved characters are A-Z,
>   a-z, 0-9, hyphen ( - ), underscore ( _
>   ), period ( . ), and tilde ( ~ ).
>
> Percent encode all other characters
>   with %XY, where X and Y are hex
>   characters 0-9 and uppercase A-F.
>
> Percent encode extended UTF-8
>   characters in the form %XY%ZA
>
> Percent encode the space character as
>   %20 (and not +, as common encoding
>   schemes do).

You'll notice that in the `python-simpledb` module, linked by Roger, they follow these rules when forming the request:

```
def escape(s):
  return urllib.quote(s, safe='-_~')

def urlencode(d):
  if isinstance(d, dict):
    d = d.iteritems()
  return '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (escape(k), escape(v)) for k, v in d])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't re-invent the wheel - there are several python simpledb libraries such as;

- https://github.com/sixapart/python-simpledb
- http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/SimpleDbIntro

If nothing else, their signing code should clarify what your mistake is, but seriously, use an existing maintained API, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: I'm actually writing a SimpleDB module for another language and using Python as a start to figure out where my mistake is. But thanks for the tips.

Comment: Cool - never heard of that one, amazing how many languages there are when in reality you can do everything in Perl ;-) Actually joking aside, you may find the Perl SimpleDB libraries useful too - there are probably more mature solutions than the Python variants.